# Knockoutjs with cascading and asynchronous dropdowns

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

Using the environment of VS2012, ASP.NET MVC 4 project, with Knockout 2.2.1 (and woefully new to it all).

I have three dropdowns that I'd like to populate, in the order of 
Manufacturer, Style, Color

I populate the Manufacturer list from an Ajax call to a WebAPI controller when the page loads, as there's only about 20.  The Style, however, may have 1000 items per Manufacturer, so naturally I don't want to send that all down the wire until I know which Manufacturer has been selected.  Additionally, I don't want to send all the Styles unless it's absolutely necessary.

Ideally, this would look like a dropdown that I can type into, and would go request a list of Styles after I've typed in three or four characters.  Alternately, if I don't have any idea the style name for which I'm looking, I can click the dropdown button and it will fetch all the styles for that manufacturer.  Once I've picked that, I can go fetch the few colors for that manufacturer+style.  However, I must pick a valid Style that the server has sent down (don't populate the color dropdown until I select a valid Style).

But that intermediate Style control is something I don't know how to do (or bind to).  Or maybe there's a different type of control (or controls) that I should be expecting to use in that type of situation.

My Viewmodel (currently doesn't contain the style or color)

```
function vmManufacturer(id, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
}

function vmItems() {
    var self = this;
    self.manufacturers = ko.observableArray([new vmManufacturer()]);
    self.selectedManufacturer = ko.observable();
    $.getJSON("/api/Manufacturer/", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            self.manufacturers.push(new vmManufacturer(val.id, val.name));
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new vmItems());
});
```

The dropdown that's currently associated with the model is the simple:

```
<select data-bind="options: manufacturers, value: selectedManufacturer, optionsText: 'name'"></select>
```

Any help would be most appreciated - my apologies for such a simple question, I'm just on shaky footing with how things get combined in JS/Knockout.

Comment: I'd like to point you in the direction of [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/).

Comment: That looks to be excellent!  A fiddle I found from that direction was http://jsfiddle.net/drosen/6XvqX/ which goes on to demo loading the select2 drop down via Ajax, with Knockout.